# How to map AWS resource type to Terraform type

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to import existing AWS resources through Terraform import cmd.

Programatically I am able to take AWS resource ID through Resource tagging API but then I can not find a proper way to map it to Terraform type.

For example EC2 instance `i-abcd` has to be imported in Terraform through the following cmd:

```
terraform import aws_instance.foo i-abcd
```

Is there any way that I can determine the Terraform type of the `i-abcd` knowing that it is an instance in AWS?

Something like a dictionary:

```
AWS Resource type | Terraform Resource type
instance          | aws_instance
```

Is there any solution like the above one out there or any workarounds to create it without too many manual mappings?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's entirely unclear what you are asking. What specific AWS resource type do you have, that you don't know how to import into Terraform? Please be specific in your question. Show a specific problem that you are currently encountering. Right now you have shown you have an AWS EC2 instance ID and you know you need to import it as an `aws_instance` Terraform resource. You haven't shown an actual problem yet.

Comment: I have resource in AWS which is `instance`. I got this instance programatically through an API. Once I get the instance I need to import it (again programatically) through Terraform `import` cmd. At this point how I am suppose to know that the type of the `instance` (AWS resource) maps to `aws_instance` - Terraform type. 
Apologies if the initial explanation was not clear

Comment: If you are querying the AWS API to get some sort of resource ID, the type of resource you are getting an ID for is inherent in the specific API call you are making. You kind of have to know enough about AWS to know that you are querying instances, or RDS servers, or ElastiCache clusters, etc... Each would be a different API call to query. At that point you should know enough about AWS to know which Terraform resource type to import just by browsing the Terraform AWS provider's API, which is broken into the same services/sections that the AWS API is.

Comment: Hey @MarkB, thanks for your answer. I am querying AWS resource tagging API which list all of the resources in provided region. So as you see it is a single API that serves all type of resources. For each resource I get ARN and from arn I can determine the type of resource and its ID. The question is - how to map this type to Terraform type. Is there some global dictionary or tool that serves this kind of an info as I wasn't able to find it out.

Comment: The global directory is the list down the left side of the page here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs

Comment: If you're looking for a way to do this all automatically/programmatically then you might look at the source code for Terraformer: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer/blob/master/docs/aws.md Note that this is not very easy, as each AWS service's API is different enough that it is almost impossible to do all this automatically in a reliable way.

Comment: Thank you @MarkB. Much appreciated. I also came to this conclusion. I will try to figure it out based on Terraformer and the resources in the registry.